# Redirect to a Rewritten URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

OK, so I'm rewriting some page URLs for a custom PHP cart.

I've got the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)$ /store.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)$ /product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

These will allow me to use a url structure like example.com/product/23/product-slug.

That part is working alright.  I'm wondering what options I have for the other direction; redirecting requests for the OLD url to the NEW url.  So for example, when someone goes to /product.php?id=2 I want to redirect to /products/2/slug.

Any idea how to get this done?

I tried a simple redirect, but would not work:

```
Redirect 301 ^/store\.php\?cat=16$ http://www.example.com/category/16/category-slug
```

Comment: fyi - `Redirect` is part of `mod_alias`, not `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a different way: with a modification to the store.php file.

I looked at output from `print_r($_SERVER)` after pinging both the normal and rewritten urls. I found that `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']` contains "/store.php" when the normal url is hit and it contains my rewritten path when the rewritten url is hit.

This means I can do a simple test and redirect appropriately:

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] == "/store.php") {
    // run some code that will generate the url
    $rewrittenURL = generateURL();
    // then add:
    header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently"); // tell spiders this is permanent
    header("Location: $rewrittenURL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect only takes a url prefix, not a regex (e.g. /store.php or /store)

You need to try RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store\.php\?cat=16$ http://www.example.com/category/16/category-slug
```

Also, is it supposed to start with a /? I'm not sure (your RewriteRule entries above start with no slash, for example)

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 ^/store\.php\?cat=16$ http://www.exmaple.com/category/16/cat-slug isn't working.